# How To Program in Delphi for Microsoft's Surface Pen?

Tags: delphi, pixelsense, surface, pen

I'd like to integrate surface pen capabilities into my application. It's written using Delphi 10 Seattle. I've searched all over the web and can't find anything.

Does anyone know how to program for the Pen? Specifically, to capture the pressure level, pen down, pen up and pen move events.

Comment: How is this done using MS tools?

Comment: Haven't tried any of this in Delphi, but have you tried a WinTab wrapper? WinTab API works for most pens/tablets, so I'd expect it to be compatible with Surface Pen(?) A quick google shows this [link](http://torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=3366&sort=Date) TTablet v1.3.1 which might work - (only mentions D5,D6,D7 support though) probably other WinTab wrappers out there?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan There is little out there for MS technology. I found little for C# but I need to look more. I think I'll probably need to find something and convert it.

Comment: @MattCoubrough thanks - I'll take a look. I should also mention I'm interested in knowing if the eraser is being used and the pressure. I'm thinking that WinTab won't have this; but I'll still take a look.

Comment: That sounds wrong. Surface is an MS device. MS provide the SDK.

Comment: Interesting comments here. The C++ surface pro 2 pen code samples at the link below don't work with surface pro 3 pens.  
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Input-simplified-ink-sample-11614bbf/view/Discussions

Answer (score 1):

Your application needs to handle the [`WM_POINTERUPDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454929(v=vs.85).aspx) message.

During that message you can call [**GetPointerPenInfo**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454887(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve information about the current status of the pointer as a [`POINTER_PEN_INFO` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
POINTER_PEN_INFO = record
   pointerInfo: POINTER_INFO;
   penFlags: PEN_FLAGS;
   penMask: PEN_MASK;
   pressure: UINT32;
   rotation UINT32;
   tiltX: INT32; 
   tiltY: INT32;
end;
```